# Leetcode 459 proof for KMP

Tags: algorithm, knuth-morris-pratt

I am looking at [Leetcode problem 459](https://leetcode.com/problems/repeated-substring-pattern/):

> #### 459. Repeated Substring Pattern
>
> Given a non-empty string check if it can be constructed by taking a substring of it and appending multiple copies of the substring together. You may assume the given string consists of lowercase English letters only and its length will not exceed 10000.

Let N be the string length, L be the length of the longest proper suffix of the string, if L is not 0, and N%(N-L) is zero, then s.substr(0, N-L) is the repeating compositional substring. I understand this statement. However, I can't figure out the opposite direction, i.e., if the string is made of repeating compositional substring, assuming its shortest length is K, then the length of the longest proper suffix of the string is N-K. Can someone kindly provide a generic proof for it?

Comment: Could you please provide definitions of the terms you use? In my understanding a "proper suffix" is any proper substring that in includes the final character, where "proper" means the substring cannot be the original string itself. So the "longest proper suffix" would always be the string with the first character removed.

Comment: you can refer to this paper https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs97si/10-string-algorithms.pdf

Comment: or this article http://jakeboxer.com/blog/2009/12/13/the-knuth-morris-pratt-algorithm-in-my-own-words/